Estou Desenvolvendo rotina em php para ler codigo de barras e carregar e mostrar que é o beneficiario
Alguém sabe dizer se para desenvolver programa para gerar os boletos precisar acessar api dos bancos para registrar os boletos, porque sem registro api dos bancos não conseguem identificar o benecifiario.
Meu problema é ler o código de barras e descobrir quem é o benecifiario, qual o tipo do boleto se é um titulo, consumo, tributo e identificar tipo de pagamento é referente a serviço, ipva, energia, telefone, agual, multa ou seja a que se refere o pagamento.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
